# Firebase Cloud function cost

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I am thinking to use the Firebase Cloud Function. But I don't understand the cost of it. Suppose, I have one Scheduled function that will be run every 3 hours later in the day. Mean 1 day it will be executed 4 times. So how much will be my cost?

Firebase Cloud Functions reference that 1 job 0.10$ per month. I don't understand this. Please help me someone who uses it or knows its full details.

Comment: What exactly will that function do? Will it interact will Firestore for example?

Comment: @AlexMamo First it will read the real-time database data then it will send the user push notification using the Firebase FCM token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Suppose, I have one Scheduled function that will be run every 3 hours later in the day. Mean 1 day it will be executed 4 times. So how much will be my cost?

The problem isn't quite about how many times you run the functions, but is about how much data you read, meaning how much bandwidth you consume. Reading data from Firebase Realtime Database in any way is always counted as a charged download. There is no exemption for traffic from Cloud Functions, or any other iOS, Android, or web clients.

If you're asking about the price of the invocations, then everything is documented [here](https://firebase.google.com/pricing). Where you'll see "Then Google Cloud pricing", then you have to check the pricing [here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/pricing).

**Edit:**

According to your last comment, you'll have **no cost** if you have:

1. Up to 2M invocations/month
2. Up to 400K GB-seconds/month
3. Up to 200K CPU-seconds/month
4. Up to 5GB Outbound networking/month
5. Up to 120min Cloud Build minutes/day
6. Up to 500MB of storage

So if you stay below these limits you'll have nothing to pay.

Comment: brother, I have been already paying for the real-time database there is no issue. I just want to know, what will be the cost for this function.

Comment: What exactly do you not understand from the pricing page?

Comment: If i run the function 4 times in a day what will be the cost after finishing the month. Only for the function not others.